# visudo + read access to file from non root user

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel, sudo

how to access the file by `visudo` from non root user

for example

when we change user to `hdfs`
and from user `hdfs` we want to print the file `file.cfg` we get Permission denied

how to configure the `visudo` in order to get read access from user `hdfs`

```
# su hdfs
$ whoami
hdfs
$ pwd
/opt/home/security
$ cat file.cfg
cat: sec.cfg: Permission denied

$ ls -ltr

-rwxr-----. 1 root root   sec.cfg
```

expected output

```
# su hdfs
$ pwd
/opt/home/security
cat file.cfg

app_q 384273462 pass BHYVF^GTYR&GV@yhgb2yr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need e.g. this line in the `sudo` configuration:

```
hdfs   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /opt/home/security/file.cfg
```

and then run these commands:

```
su hdfs
sudo /bin/cat /opt/home/security/file.cfg
```